# How to get the Temporary recorded videopath in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to know is it possible to get the temporary path of the video that has been recorded in iphone?I want to create  an app that record through iphone and then saved the video to a place where I want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` in the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html).  You're given a path to the video the user just recorded.

Comment: Thanx David its working....
To save the video the user has to click a use button.Now I want that to be remove....The video should be saved without touch of the use button i.e as soon as the user touch the stop button....Is there a way to do that?Please show me the way.

Comment: Is there no way to get the path of a video without using the - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  function??Please its very urgent....

Comment: no way to do this at present, but it seems likely Apple will add this to the iPhone OS eventually, as they did for taking still images.  If you don't care about whether your app is approved for sale, you might be able to find a way to simulate a press on the button yourself if you hack around in the view hierarchy.